# Server IP Address Change Breaks Facebook Login?

Tags: facebook, authentication, ip

This morning we had our IP address changed for one of our servers (including DNS entries) and after testing we discovered that Facebook login for one of our sites is no longer functional.

The sandbox version of the site, running on a different server, still functions as expected.

Can this IP change be linked to the issue? I only see domain name properties on the Facebook Developers site.

Error shown when clicking Facebook login button:

[image: Error shown when clicking Facebook login button]

Comment: Check if the sandbox mode is not enabled

Comment: Thank you. It turned out our client had this enabled for some reason!